# Parse a simple update statement

Tags: sql

I was wondering if someone could help me on this problem.

I am trying to parse an update statement as below.

```
Update tableA set 
column1 = NULL
where column2 is NULL
```

Given the above sql statement as an input. 
I need the below to the output.

1. I need the table name when is getting. in this case : `TableA`
2. I need the column which is getting updated . in this case `Column1`
3. I need the value the column is getting updated to . in this case `NULL`
4. I need the where condition as a whole . in this case column2 is `NULL`

Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is wrong with your update statement?

Comment: "segregate" is not a verb normally used when describe SQL statements.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the update statement. i am trying to dynamically find what any simple update query is made up of. Do i make sense ?

Comment: _Parse_ is perhaps a better word. You need the full SQL grammar.

Comment: Yes...correct @jarlh

Comment: In your situation would the table or column name be surrounded with brackets consistently? If so, you might be able to use that.

Comment: How smart does that parser have to be? Is it always these three lines, or can you have multiple columns and/or conditions? Maybe it's enough to find the positions of the keywords `UPDATE`, `SET` and `WHERE` and work from there.

Comment: Please add the tag for the appropriate parser language.  You have one answer in JavaScript, but there is nothing in the question to indicate the desired language.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to parse statement but no implement parser then I would try to find existing library. There is Javascript library which parse SQL: [node-sqlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sqlparser):

```
'use strict';
// npm install node-sqlparser

let parser = require('node-sqlparser');
let tree =parser.parse(`Update tableA set 
column1 = NULL
where column2 is NULL`);

console.info(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

result:

```
{
  "type": "update",
  "db": "",
  "table": "tableA",
  "set": [
    {
      "column": "column1",
      "value": {
        "type": "null",
        "value": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "where": {
    "type": "binary_expr",
    "operator": "IS",
    "left": {
      "type": "column_ref",
      "table": "",
      "column": "column2"
    },
    "right": {
      "type": "null",
      "value": null
    }
  },
  "params": []
}
```